# Does cardinality matter when chosing the order of the composite key columns?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table

`Invoice(PosId,InvoiceId,Name,...)` with PK: (PosId, InvoiceId)

and a detail table

`InvoiceEntry(PosId, InvoiceId, EntryId, Product, Price)`

- The cardinality of `PosId` is 10 range: [1...10]
- The cardinality of `InvoiceId`is 1,000,000 range [1...999999]

When doing joins both `PosId` and `InvoiceId` are always used. (There is no usecase where someone would use only one of the two columns when querying)

Does the cardinality of each column play a role on which one of the two I should pick as the first column of the primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is an old myth. The order doesn't matter as long as both columns are compared with `=`.

If one column is compared with the equality operator and the other with a different operator (`<`, `<=`, `>`, `>=`, `IN`), put the column that is compared with `=` first to avoid scanning unnecessary index entries.

Answer (score 0):

Compound PostgreSQL index should always start with the column with more distinct values. Cardinality matters.